# What's the most popular compression algorithm inside voip projects?

Tags: algorithm, voip, voice

What's the most popular compression algorithm inside voip projects, or what's the most popular voice compression algorithm for internet transfer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of the open source speex codec seems very common.